# How to compare variables in for loop bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create if statement, but in this statement are some errors

```
for i in ${@:2} ; do
 if (( $2 -eq $i ))
         then 
         continue
         fi
    done
```

How to fix my if statement

Comment: share the error itself, have you looked at http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/

Answer (score 2):

Your statement only works for integers.

If you want to compare them as strings, you can use `[[ "string1" = "string2" ]]`:

```
$ cat -v myscript 
#!/bin/bash
for i in "${@:2}" ; do
  if [[ "$2" = "$i" ]]
  then
    echo "$2 and $i are the same"
  else
    echo "$2 and $i are different"
  fi
done

$ chmod +x myscript
$ ./myscript dummy target foo bar target
target and target are the same
target and foo are different
target and bar are different
target and target are the same
```

As you can see from this runnable example, it works. If you find that it doesn't on your system, you should provide a complete example like the above demonstrating it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

```
if [ "$2" = "$i" ]
```